# Firebase authentication - refreshToken automatic refresh

Tags: android, ios, react-native, firebase-authentication, react-native-firebase

I am developing a react-native application which will use firebase authentication, and I have some doubts about how refresh tokens should work.
I am using the react native package https://rnfirebase.io/ `"@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.9.0"` and so far everything works great (login/account-creation, password reset flow, etc)

However, I have doubts about how the idToken should be refreshed.
From the [documentation](https://rnfirebase.io/reference/auth#onIdTokenChanged), and several posts ([post1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66575452/how-do-i-use-a-firebase-refresh-token-to-persist-authentication), [post2 with similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71721333/how-to-refresh-firebase-token-after-it-has-expired), [post3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57570815/how-do-i-persist-user-authentication-using-the-firebase-refresh-token), etc), my understanding is that the react native package uses the android & ios SDK which should be managing token refreshes for me and dispatching the `onIdTokenChanged` event when the idToken expires and is refreshed. I read that the idToken expires in 1h, so I would expect the token to be refreshed every hour.

In practice however I don't see this behavior.
Here is a minimal reprod of what I set up in app with logging when the onIdTokenChanged event is dispatched, and when the idToken actually expires

```js
const [ user, setUser ] = useState(null)

// Listens to onIdTokenChanged
useEffect(() => {
  auth().onIdTokenChanged((_user) => {
    console.log('auth//test//onIdTokenChanged')
    setUser(_user)
  })
}, [])

// Sets a timer on idToken expiry
useEffect(() => {
  if (!user) {
    return
  }

  (async function () {
    const idTokenResult = await user.getIdTokenResult()
    const expirationDate = new Date(idTokenResult.expirationTime)
    const expiresIn = expirationDate.getTime() - Date.now()
    console.log(`auth//test//tokenWillExpireIn:${expiresIn / 60000}min`)

    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log('auth//test//tokenExpired')
    }, expiresIn)
  })()
}, [ user ])
```

And here are the resulting logs after login:

```
2022-05-13T09:47:05.156Z: auth//test//onIdTokenChanged
2022-05-13T09:47:05.238Z: auth//test//onIdTokenChanged
2022-05-13T09:47:05.274Z: auth//test//tokenWillExpireIn:59.09545min
2022-05-13T09:47:05.358Z: auth//test//tokenWillExpireIn:59.094033333333336min
2022-05-13T10:46:11.015Z: auth//test//tokenExpired
2022-05-13T10:46:11.018Z: auth//test//tokenExpired
END
```

Result is: onIdTokenChanged is dispatched on app start twice, then an hour later the token expires, but why is the onIdTokenChanged not dispatched again when the token expires ?

Am I setting up something incorrectly/did I misunderstand the documentation?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**EDIT**
After some more research it seems the `onIdTokenChanged` event is dispatched *lazily*, as in only when you invoke `getIdToken()` and it sees the token should be refreshed.
I read this behavior in an [issue in the js sdk](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/issues/2985), and seems to be indicated in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69070770/how-to-auto-refresh-the-idtoken-when-using-firebase-auth) when reading between the lines.
I did some testing, and indeed it seems to be the case

Can someone confirm this whether these `onIdTokenChanged`/`onAuthStateChanged` events are triggered lazily?
The documentation doesn't seem clear about this